# How to print colorful text in Python terminal?

Tags: python, printing, colors

I know this question have been raised at Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

So I've tried the following code from `joeld`'s answer.

Here is the code in IDLE (I am using Python 2.7):

```
print '\033[95m'+'my text'+'\033[95m'
```

and I got the output without color changed:

```
[95mmy text[95m
```

===============================================================================

Then I also tried the package `colorama`. The package was installed within `cmd`:

```
python setup.py install
```

and tried following code in Aptana Studio 3:

```
from colorama import *

print (Fore.GREEN + 'Green text')
print (Fore.Red + 'Red text')
```

I got following output:

```
[32mGreen text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Practice\test_colorama.py", line 12, in <module>
    print (Fore.Red + 'Red text')
AttributeError: 'AnsiCodes' object has no attribute 'Red'
```

===============================================================================

So now I am really confused. These solutions are upvoted hundreds of times which implies that it should be effective, but in my case it seems not.

May I know how I can print colorful text in the terminal or console?

Many thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `RED` and not `Red`?

Comment: I tried your first example in a vanilla CPython shell, and in an IPython shell, and it worked both times.

Comment: There are also several terminals out there :) And it would be great if you mention which one you used. Some terminals don't support color at all.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `Red`

```
>>> import colorama
>>> colorama.Fore.Red
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'AnsiCodes' object has no attribute 'Red'
```

But, `RED` exists:

```
>>> colorama.Fore.RED
'\x1b[31m'
```

Comment: Hi, Flasetru.  Thanks for the answer. I've tried to change `Red` into `RED` and there is no more error report. However, the color of text in the Console of Aptana Studio 3 remains black.

Comment: @ChangeMyName, `colorama` packages is for normal terminals/terminal emulators. Try the code in terminal (not in IDLE, Apatana, ...)

Comment: I've tried `colorama` in Apatana Studio 3. The output is `[32mGreen text` and no color change.

Comment: @ChangeMyName, I'll not repeat the same comment. :(

Answer (score 1):

IDLE is not a proper shell. Do this from a Python session in a normal terminal.